# Linux Shell Command: Find. How to Sort and Exec without using Pipes?

Tags: linux, find

Linux command `find` with argument `exec` does a GREAT job executing commands on files/folders regardless whether they contain spaces and special characters.  For example:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Works great to run `md5sum` on each file in a directory tree, but executes in a **random** order.  Find does not sort the results, and requires piping to `sort` to get results in a more human-readable ordering.  However, piping to `sort` eliminates the benefits of `exec`.

This does not work:

```
find . -type f | sort | md5sum
```

Because some filenames contain spaces and special characters.

Also does not work:

```
find . -type f | sort | sed 's/ /\\ /g' | md5sum
```

Still does not recognize spaces are part of the filename.

I suppose I can always sort the final result later, but wonder if someone knows an easy way to avoid that extra step by sorting within `find`?

Comment: The spaces aren't the problem there. `md5sum`, reading from stdin, doesn't expect a list of filenames, but a single stream to be hashed.

Comment: That said -- **which** implementation of `find`? BSD find can do internal sorting; GNU find cannot (but the GNU toolchain is powerful enough to offer other approaches).

Comment: BTW, unless you had literal newlines in your filenames, `find . -type f | sort | xargs -d $'\n' md5sum` would work. I hesitate to make that an answer, because having known bugs (in this case, the literal-newline case) isn't good practice -- even if a bug represents an obscure corner case, sometimes an attacker can make a security hole of such a corner-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### With BSD `find`

A `-s` argument is available to request lexographic sort order.

```
find . -s -type f -exec md5sum -- '{}' +
```

---

#### With GNU `find`

Use NUL delimiters to allow filenames to be processed unambiguously. Assuming you have GNU tools:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum
```

Comment: Thanks, Charles! Using NUL delimiters is a great idea! I use gnu `find`, and have no `-s`

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort -k 1.33
```

Sorts the results by comparing the characters starting after the 32 character `md5sum` result, producing a readable/sorted list.

Comment: FYI, `-exec md5sum {} \;` is much slower than `-exec md5sum {} +`, as it loads a new copy of md5sum for every file to process.

Comment: Thanks. Replaced my `\;` with `+` and edited solution from `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 1.33` to use a `+` instead